# Trying to use get/set methods

Tags: java, methods, get, set, accessor

Take a look in the Circle class. Each time the if statement evals to true, i'd like the counter increment by one. I'm trying to get a set method to do this work for me, but when I check the value of counter in the main method it's not counting. Any tips?

```
package circle;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics; 
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JApplet;


public class Shapes extends JApplet {

private int squareLength = 0;
private int count = 0;
private double areaSquares = 0;
private double areaCircle = 0;

public void setPixelDimOfSquare(int width) {squareLength = width;}

public void setCount(int n) {count = n++;}

public int getCount() {return count;}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    //shapes
    //adds sphere (xcoord,ycoord,width of framing rect, height of framing rect)
    g2.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 1000, 1000));

    //builds square grid and counts number of whole squares in the circle.
    for (int i = 0; squareLength*i <= 1000; i++){
        for (int j = 0; squareLength*j <= 1000; j++) {

         if(new Ellipse2D.Double(0,0,1000,1000).contains(new Rectangle2D.Double(squareLength*i,squareLength*j,squareLength,squareLength))){
             setCount(1);
             g2.setColor(Color.black);
             g2.fillRect(squareLength*i,squareLength*j,squareLength,squareLength);
         } else {
             g2.drawRect(squareLength*i,squareLength*j,squareLength,squareLength);
         }
        }
    } 
    System.out.println("Shape: There are " + getCount() + " squares in the circle.");
} 

public double areaSquares() {
    areaSquares = Math.pow(squareLength,2) * count;
    return areaSquares;
}

public double areaCircle() {

    areaCircle = Math.PI * Math.pow(1000, 2);
    return areaCircle;


}
}
```

Now for main

```
package circle;

import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Gets the desired number of boxes
    //Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    //System.out.print("Please enter number of boxes:");
    //double boxes = sc.nextDouble();

    // Builds frame for shapes.
    Shapes shape = new Shapes();
    shape.setPixelDimOfSquare(10);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Draw Shapes Demo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.getContentPane().add(shape);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(1000,1000);
    frame.setVisible(true);


    System.out.println("Main: There are " + shape.getCount() + " squares in the circle.");
}
}
```

Comment: `Shapes` shouldn't extend from `JApplet` if you intend to use window based containers.  You should be using something more like `JPanel` and overriding it's `paintComponent` method (and calling `super.paintComponent` before you do any custom painting)

Comment: It's possible that when *"System.out.println("Main: There are " + shape.getCount() + " squares in the circle.");"* nothing has been painted...

Comment: @MadProgrammer i'll look into playing around with paint component. 

paint() is definitely drawing the shapes for me. I can see them in the frame.

Comment: A `Applet` is conceptually it's own top level container and is suppose to be managed by a web browser, it has it's own requirements for initialization and managed which are beyond the scope of windows based containers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your setCount as:

```
public void setCount(){
  count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is your problem:

```
public void setCount(int n) {count = n++;}
```

When you say `count = n++;`, it is equivalent to

```
count = n;
n = n + 1;
```

because `n++` is the post-increment operator.
This is probably not the behaviour that you want. If instead you put

```
public void setCount(int n) {count+= n;}
```

It will increase `count` by `n` every time the method is called. The `+=` operator is just shorthand for `count = count + n`

---

Also, naming the method `setCount` is a bit misleading if it actually increases count by the given number. It implies that it will set `count = n` instead of `count = count + n`. I would recommend renaming it to `incrementCount`.

And personally, for something this simple, I wouldn't even bother with getters and setters. Just define an `int count` before your for loop and use `count++` to increment it every time the if statement evaluates to true

Comment: Thank you for this. I really appreciate your help.  When I run this the getCount() Shapes class is 7628 , but getCount() in main is 0. What's up with that?

Comment: This happens because your program doesn't do any calculations until AWT asks it to (which can happen any time), which (in your case) doesn't happen until after your System.out.println call.

Comment: Do you have a resource where I could learn more? I thought putting the System.out.println at the end of main would make it call last after count had been incremented.

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't. If you want to print after all the calculations are done, I'd put the System.out.println statement at the end of your paint() method. However, this will print it out every time AWT decides that your component needs repainting unless you implement additional logic

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `setCount` method to this:

```
    public void setCount() {count++;}
```

Your code sets `count` to 2 each time that it is called in the `paint` method.

Comment: `n++` where n = 1 evaluates to 1 because it's a post-increment operator

Comment: That shouldn't be in issue in this case.

Comment: It's not the solution to the problem, but it's an inaccuracy in the answer.